# Spring Security User and Admin Configuration problem

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am building a web app in Spring Boot.
I am have to two login pages one for admin and the other for normal users. 
I have created the security config like below but I have problems when I try to login as user in this case if I change the `@Order(1)` at `UserConfiguration` to `@Order(1)` and `@Order(2)` at `AdminConfigurerAdapter`, work user login and admin login doesn't work.

Did anyone had this problem?

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/image/**",
            "/newUser",
            "/forgetPassword",
            "/",
            "/login",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/admin/adminLogin"
    };

    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    @Order(2)
    public static class UserConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    /*  .antMatchers("/**")*/
                    .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN");
            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/jobList")
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                    .deleteCookies("remember-me")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .rememberMe();
        }

        @Autowired
        private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;
        private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
        }
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }
      } 

    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    @Order(1)
    public static class AdminConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");
            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/adminHome")
                    .loginPage("/admin/adminLogin")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                    .deleteCookies("remember-me")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .rememberMe();
        }

        @Autowired
        private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;
        private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .userDetailsService(userSecurityService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I can access both user and admin login page but user account can't login. Any idea? I can still login only to my admin account.

Comment: That's a new problem. Close this question (accept the dupe) and open a new question with your new configuration and the new error message. You are using the same `UserDetailsService` for user and admin, so I would think you could login or you couldn't login independently of user or admin.